# Explanation of boost::sp_convertible

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, shared-ptr

I am getting the following error when try to convert a `boost::shared_ptr` of a derived class to a `boost::shared_ptr` of the parent class:

```
1>c:\program files\boost\boost_1_52_0\boost\smart_ptr\detail\sp_convertible.hpp(48) : error C2594: 'argument' : ambiguous conversions from 'Title_Id_Record *' to 'Component::Interface *'
1>        c:\program files\boost\boost_1_52_0\boost\smart_ptr\detail\sp_convertible.hpp(66) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::sp_convertible<Y,T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Y=Title_Id_Record,
1>            T=Component::Interface
1>        ]
```

Here is the inheritance diagram, according to Doxygen, for Title_Id_Record: 
*(All inheritance is public.)* 
[image]

Here is the text of the `boost::sp_convertable` structure:

```
template< class Y, class T > struct sp_convertible
{
    typedef char (&yes) [1];
    typedef char (&no)  [2];

    static yes f( T* );
    static no  f( ... );

    enum _vt { value = sizeof( (f)( static_cast<Y*>(0) ) ) == sizeof(yes) };
};
```

My questions:

1. How does the `boost::sp_convertible` structure work for detecting
   compatibility?
2. Why is a boost shared pointer of `Title_Id_Record` not convertible
   to a boost shared pointer of `Component::Interface`?

Thanks.

*FYI, I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows Vista with Boost 1.52.0.*

**Edit 1: SCCE**

```
namespace Component
{
    class Interface {};
}

namespace Record
{
    class Interface
        : public ::Component::Interface
    {};
    class Table_Association
        : public Record::Interface
    {};
    class With_Id
        : public Record::Table_Association
    {};
    class Of_Shared_Pointers
        : public Record::Table_Association
    {};
    class Shared_Ptr_With_Id
        : public Record::With_Id,
          public Record::Of_Shared_Pointers
    {};
    class Shared_Ptr_Id_String
        : public Record::Shared_Ptr_With_Id
    {};
    class Title_Id_Record
        : public Record::Shared_Ptr_Id_String
    {};

}
```

Comment: What double arrows mean on this diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet the inheritance of `Record::Table_Association` is non-`virtual`: In that case you have two hierarchies of subobjects in your inheritance and the compiler has no idea which one to choose. Here is an example:

```
// #define USE_VIRTUAL
struct CInterface {};
struct RInterface: CInterface {};
struct RTableAssociation: RInterface {};
struct RWithId: USE_VIRTUAL RTableAssociation {};
struct ROfSharedPointers: USE_VIRTUAL RTableAssociation {};
struct RSharedPtrWithId: RWithId, ROfSharedPointers {};
struct TitleIdRecord: RSharedPtrWithId {};

int main()
{
    TitleIdRecord r;
    CInterface* c = &r;
}
```

(BTW, you could have created this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), too). To fix the problem uncomment the `#define USE_VIRTUAL virtual` line. Whether you use this code with `boost::shared_ptr<T>` or not doesn't really matter: the type traits just determined if there is a [non-ambiguous] conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the good inspection.  But how does the boost::sp_convertible work?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Well, it just tries to call `f()` with a pointer to the derived, i.e., `Y*`. If the tested type `T` is a base, `f(T*)` is a better match than `f(...)` and the size of the result will be the size of `yes` rather than the size of `no`. That is, all it really need to test to determine the `value` of the test is that `sizeof(f(static_cast<Y*>(0))) == sizeof(yes)`. Neat trick.

Comment: Oh I understand now, the expression f(..) actually "calls" the function `f` (as a constexpr), and therefore returns an instance of the type of `f`'s return's type. taking its sizeof therefore takes the sizeof the return type. Where I was befuddled was that in the original they use parenthesis which makes it look like they are taking the pointer to `f`. which should not have a comparable sizeof.